# How to use Current Year in Content Search Webpart

Tags: 2013, cswp

I have a requirement where I need to show items where Date lies in current year. So it would be like : Show all documents created in current year.

Is there a way to create a Today() managed property which always have current year? Or is there any way I can create a CSWP query to extract year from Today?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me:

ContentType:Document AND Created:"this year"

Placing this in the Query Text box in the Advanced search mode of the query builder yielded only documents created this year.

Check out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx for more info.